# React / firebase app flashes login screen before auth finishes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, react-router

When you signup/ login/ refresh the page the login page flashes just before going to the correct page. I tried putting a loader in but all it does is do a loader animation before it flashes then goes to correct page. Any idea how to get this to not happen?

```
function App(){
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoad] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), setUser, setLoad(false))
    return () => {unsubscribe()}
  }, [])
const AuthenticatedRoute = ({children}) => {
  let isAuthenticated;
    if(user !=null){
      isAuthenticated = true;
    }else{
      isAuthenticated = false;
    }
    if(!loading){
      return isAuthenticated? children: <Navigate to="/signin"/>
    }else{
      return <Loading/>
    }
  
}

const UnauthenticatedRoute = ({children}) => {
  let isAuthenticated;
    if(user !=null){
      isAuthenticated = true;
    }else{
      isAuthenticated = false;
    }
    if(!loading){
      return !isAuthenticated? children: <Navigate to="/home"/>
    }else{
      return <Loading/>
    }
  
}

      return(
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
          {
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<UnauthenticatedRoute><PreHome/></UnauthenticatedRoute>}/>
            <Route path='/home' element={<AuthenticatedRoute><Home/></AuthenticatedRoute>} />
            <Route exact path="/signin" element={<UnauthenticatedRoute><Signin/></UnauthenticatedRoute>} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" element={<UnauthenticatedRoute><Signup/></UnauthenticatedRoute>} />
          </Routes>
          }
      </div>
      </Router>
      )
  }
```

Sign Out code:
This one line has been working for signing out

```
<button onClick={() => signOut(getAuth())}>Sign Out</button>
```

Sign In code:

```
async function OnFormSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const auth = getAuth();
        try{
            isLoading(true);
            await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pw)
            isLoading(false);
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issues

1. The loading state is only cleared when there's an error in `onAuthStateChanged`.
2. The route protector components are declared ***inside*** another React component. This is anti-pattern. When new "instances" of these components are declared each time the parent `App` component rerenders, it will unmount/mount the component's subReactTree.
3. The components don't wait for the user's authentication status to resolve before deciding to redirect or render the routed content.

## Solution

- Move the route protector components out on their own. Render an `Outlet` for nested routes to be rendered into. This allows you to render these as layout routes instead of individual wrapper components.
- Use a proper "loading" state. Use undefined `user` state as the "loading state".

Example:

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ user }) => {
  if (user === undefined) return <Loading />;

  return user
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/signin" />;
};

const UnauthenticatedRoute = ({ user }) => {
  if (user === undefined) return <Loading />;

  return user
    ? <Navigate to="/home" />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

...

```
function App(){
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), setUser);
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return(
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<UnauthenticatedRoute user={user} />}>
              <Route path="/" element={<PreHome />} />
              <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin />} />
              <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
            </Route>
            <Route element={<AuthenticatedRoute user={user} />}>
              <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for eliminating the flash! However it ran into a problem that wasnt a problem before, where if i sign out i have to refresh to get the effect of it, same with sign in... Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: @Matt102065 What/where/how are you signing in/out? I noticed you have a `AuthContextProvider` component, but for some reason the `user` state and the `onAuthStateChanged` call seem to be outside it. What purpose is this `AuthContextProvider` component serving? Can you add the `AuthContextProvider` code and the other relevant code for signing in and out to your question so we've better context?

Comment: I forgot to remove AuthContextProvider as that is no longer in use. I added the sign out and sign in above.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing but the fix was i called unsubscribe(); instead of just unsubscribe;

Comment: Your solution works perfectly thank you, I want to upvote but it says I dont have enough reputation

Comment: @Matt102065 Thanks, glad it's all working for you now. Yeah, you can vote when you have 15 rep I believe. Cheers and good luck!